# What was this lawyer eating?

Tags: house-of-cards

There is a comical scene in "Chapter 54" ([*House of Cards*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1856010/), S05E02), roughly 3 minutes into the episode, in which Walter Doyle eats some candies and Seth Grayson expresses surprise. What was that Frank Underwood's associate eating?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I read that as "A lawyer ate some candles..."

Comment: Candy corn.  That stuff is the best!  LOL

Comment: @Criggie : There are those who would claim there is no difference between candy corn and candle wax.  (I'm not one, at least for candy corn that hasn't been stored for months...)

Comment: I know it doesn't look like it in the pictures but the lawyer actually ate souls.

Comment: @sbecker, What is `souls`? Add link? Picture?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Pretty sure that's [**candy corn**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candy_corn), a common Halloween candy in the US (note that the episode indeed takes place during Halloween):

[image]

Answer (score 28):

It's candy corn. The joke is that many people don't like candy corn.

- "[The 9 Most-Hated Halloween Treats](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/10/28/the-9-most-hated-halloween-treats_n_4161975.html)," Huffington Post

  > 1. CANDY CORN
- "[6 Reasons Why Candy Corn is the Worst Part of Halloween](https://spoonuniversity.com/lifestyle/candy-corn-is-the-worst)", Spoon University
- "It's not candy, it's not corn, it's earwax formed in the shape of a rotten tooth." Gordon Ramsay as quoted in "[Gordon Ramsay Ranks the Absolute Worst Types of Halloween Candy](https://www.eater.com/2016/10/26/13416158/gordon-ramsay-halloween-candy)", Eater.com
- "[Explaining The Logic Behind Candy Corn Hatred](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/10/25/candy-corn-hate_n_4158096.html)", Huffington Post